# JavaScript task scheduler (batch treatment)

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, batch-processing, scheduler

I'm searching a software or a framework compatible with Linux. I want it to calculate statistics each midnight. I want to get data in multiple mongodb tables, calculate some statistics and store it in another mongodb table. I want to make a little data warehouse.

I have seen several npm modules in nodeJS which permit that. Is it a good solution? Does there exist a new technology which permits the scheduling jobs like that? Or other with web interface?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on just how complex you want to make the system.  You could easily use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to run a particular task at any given interval that you would like.  You could also utilize a job queue system such as [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) to process many smaller jobs and interact with it via the RESTful API.

Only you can determine what the overall architecture will end up looking like, but there are many viable solutions that could be implemented via Node.js

Comment: Ok thanks, after nodeJS and Linux cron what is the other way to schedule jobs in Linux ? It exist a recommended way ?